# python not strict type check for bool

Tags: python

I have always read that python has strict type checks -

```
>>> 1 + 'hello'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

This is fine since we cannot add int to a string

But why is the following allowed  ?

```
>>> True + False
1
>>> True + 0
1
```

Why is strict checking not supported while adding int to a boolean ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

That explains everything.  That is, `bool` is a subclass of `int`.  That's why you can use a `bool` anywhere an `int` is allowed.

For a lot of detail, [see the PEP that introduced the type](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).

**EDIT: gloss**

Note that Python didn't have a `bool` type for the first decade of its life.  Conceptually "true/false" operations usually returned 1 or 0 instead.  And Python programmers exploited that as often as, say, K&R C programmers exploited it.  For example,

```
sum(x < 2 for x in some_list)
```

returned the number of elements in `some_list` less than 2.  When adding the `bool` type, of course operators like `<` had to be changed to return `True` or `False` instead, but an *enormous* amount of code relying on 1 or 0 return values would have been broken.  That's a key reason for why `bool` was made a subtype of `int`, restricted to the values 0 and 1 (with the fancier names `False` and `True`).

Comment: I see. Link explain everything ! Thanks @Tim. Getting to learn new things daily!

Answer (score 6):

Because Python's boolean type is a subclass of integer.

Answer (score 1):

`True or False` simply evaluates to:

```
>>> 1 or 0
1
```

and `True + 0` evaluates to the same thing

eg:

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

The `or` statement returns `True` if one of the arguments is `True`

Comment: Here i think + stands as arithmetic operator only True + 0 evaluates to 1 and 0 - True evaluates to -1 so + is arithmetic not a Boolean operator

Comment: @amar then why does `False or 55` evaluate to 55 and `False + 55` also evaluate to 55? clarify a bit please...

Comment: True is Bool equivalent of 1 and false is bool equivalent of 0  to clarify pls do in Python True + True + True you will understand Python's boolean type is a subclass of integer.

Comment: You are absolutely correct when it comes to Boolean algebra but in python context its little different..

Comment: `False or 55` evaluates to `55` for the same reason that `False or 'hello'` evaluates to `'hello'`. It is a different operator from addition; you can do `False + 55` only because `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python. You cannot do `False + 'hello'`.

Answer (score 1):

PEP 285:

> This PEP proposes the introduction of a new built-in type, bool,
>       with two constants, False and True.  The bool type would be a
>       straightforward subtype (in C) of the int type, and the values
>       False and True would behave like 0 and 1 in most respects (for
>       example, False==0 and True==1 would be true) except repr() and
>       str().  All built-in operations that conceptually return a Boolean
>       result will be changed to return False or True instead of 0 or 1;
>       for example, comparisons, the "not" operator, and predicates like
>       isinstance().

it's possible because `True is also 1` and `False is also 0` (and vice versa):

```
>>> 1 + False
1
>>>
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> True + 2
3
>>> False
False
>>> False + 4
4
>>>
>>> type(True+1)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

also you have to know that `None type` is not eqvivalent to `0`:

```
>>> None + True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'bool'
>>>
>>> None is 0
False
```

Comment: I agree, but I am asking why is it allowed ?

Comment: added pep 285 short summary

Comment: @TimPeters you are really Tim Peters?!?!

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry, I think so - but on the Web anyone can be anyone ;-)