# Simple if-statement in Python, testing for mutual exclusiveness

Tags: python

I am doing some stuff in python, but I am not that used to it yet.

This is what I want the code to do (pseudocode):

```
if x in list or y in list but not x and y:
    #do-stuff
```

the first part is correct (`if x in list or y in list`) but I don't know what to write after that. The `but not x and y`part.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I am iterating through a set of lists. I want it to only do calculations if the list contains X or Y but not both.

Comment: use xor: `(x in list) ^ (y in list)`

Comment: do the if and check first,

Comment: If the primary operation you want to perform on `list` is membership tests, you should use a set instead.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably go for using a `set` here instead...

```
if len({x, y}.intersection(your_list)) == 1:
    # do something
```

This has the advantage that it only needs to iterate once over `your_list`.

**Example**:

```
examples = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [100, 101, 102, 103, 104]
]

for example in examples:
    overlap = {1, 5}.intersection(example)
    print 'overlap is', overlap, 'with a length of', len(overlap)

# overlap is set([1, 5]) with a length of 2
# overlap is set([5]) with a length of 1
# overlap is set([]) with a length of 0
```

Comment: Thanks. But behzad.nouri's answer solved it for me. I used xor: "`(x in list) ^ (y in list)`"

Comment: @user3685412 indeed... they both work... but `(x in list) ^ (y in list)` has to scan `list` twice to compute the either/or

Comment: Oh okay. That's nice. I'll definitely use yours then. The list is pretty big :)

Comment: @user3685412 note: you can't use this approach if `x` and `y` happen to be unhashable...

Comment: On the other hand, your solution needs to create a temporary set. It's a classic time vs. space tradeoff, but with no change in complexity.

Comment: @user4815162342 indeed, but a two element set is hardly a monstrous overhead and the intersection operation is efficient.

Comment: @JonClements Good point, I missed the fact that you're only creating a short constant-length set, so I retract my comment.

Answer (score 1):

With "but" spelled `and` and a pair of parentheses, you can use:

```
x_in_list = x in list
y_in_list = y in list
if (x_in_list or y_in_list) and not (x_in_list and y_in_list):
    ...
```

Or, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586208/simple-if-statement-in-python/24586253#comment38087939_24586208) by behzad.nouri, use xor:

```
if (x in list) ^ (y in list):
    ...
```

This is shorter, but possibly less understandable to a non-CS-savvy reader.

Answer (score 1):

Exclusive or means "one or the other, but not both" and maps perfectly in what you want to do:

```
if (x in list) ^ (y in list):
    ...
```

looks a bit weird because normally xor is only used for bitwise operations, but here works because Python will implicitly convert `True` and `False` to 1 and 0, making the operator work as expected in an `if`.

Note however that the parenthesis are necessary because the xor operator `^` has an higher precedence than `in` (it's most often used for bitwise math, so this choice is reasonable).

Comment: Note that `True` and `False` aren't *converted* to 1 and 0, in a very real sense they [already *are*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20756275/1600898) 1 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Jon Clements's centi-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801605/1903116),

```
items, it = {x, y}, (i in items for i in lst)
print(any(it) and not any(it))
```

This short-circuit version is better, in the negative cases.

`it` is an iterator of the original list, and we check if any of `it` is in `items`, if yes we check if all the other items are not in `items`.

**Note:** This works only if the `items` are unique in `lst`